# Performance issue when calling a SP from C# ADO.Net, which SP reads data from multiple DBs located in same server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, ado.net

I am calling a Stored Procedure **(SP Name: stp1, DB Name:DB1, server:localhost)** from C# code by passing the right parameters by opening the connection to DB1 with below connection string.  Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4000.0 (X64)

> "Data Source=.\;" + "Initial Catalog=DB1;" + " Integrated
>   Security=SSPI;";

Inside SP **"stp1"** reads data from the table "**table1**" located in **DB2** in the same server.

When I run the SP stp1 with the above connection string then the **execution time is: 5 seconds**

If I create the same SP in DB2 and if I run stp1 then **execution time is: .02 seconds**

we have the same environment in multiple machines, we are not seeing this problem in all the machines and we are seeing this especially in one server, so is this something due to server configuration or any idea???

Since the other way is faster, I would agree that we can create SP in DB2, but I would like to understand why this is happening??

Comment: Start comparing environments.  Is named pipes on the slow server.

Comment: @Blam, How to check this?

Comment: Search msdn for sql namedpipes.

Comment: I checked it in both machines, it is enables in both machines.